# Display a file with cat in a expect file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, expect

I try to automate some tasks with an exepect file, but when I try to send cat and display my file nothing happens, the file exists, I can display it when I type the command manually.
I have the impression that it is working in the background, but this is not the result I expect.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set ip [ lindex $argv 0 ]
set port [ lindex $argv 1 ]
set user [ lindex $argv 2 ]
set password [ exec cat "../../flag04/flag" ]

spawn ssh "$user\@$ip" "-p $port"

expect "password:" { send "$password\r" }

send "echo 'bin/getflag >> /tmp/flag05' >> /opt/openarenaserver/script.sh\r"

expect ":~$" { send "cat /tmp/flag05\r" }

interact
```

[image]

Comment: Run with `expect -d script.exp` and see what's happening. Is `":~$"` a (glob) pattern that actually matches the prompt?

Comment: Does anyone actually invoke the generated script.sh?

Comment: @glennjackman That doesn't match with the prompt, i add a screenshot result to the question, that match with an other output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just find the anwser, it missed a space after `:$`  after the dollar sign

Comment: I'd use a regexp pattern: `expect -re {\$ $}` -- a literal dollar, a space, end of string.